# Show that there are arbitrarily large intervals of consecutive integers, none of which is free of squares.

Tags: number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

> **Definition:**A whole number is free of squares if it is not divisible by the square of any whole number greater than $ 1 $.

Consider the next arbitrary interval of consecutive integers $ (m + 1, m + 2, \ldots, m + (n-1), m + n) $. So, by Chinese remainder theorem we will have to, $$\left\{\begin{align*}
m&\equiv-1\pmod{2^2}\\
m&\equiv-2\pmod{3^2}\\
m&\equiv-3\pmod{5^2}\\
m&\equiv-4\pmod{7^2}\\
&\;\;\vdots\\
m&\equiv-n\pmod{p_n^2}
\end{align*}\right.$$
Thus, we have found arbitrarily large intervals which are divisible by the square of an integer greater than $ 1 $. This ends the test. It's okay?

Comment: The idea is correct but the argument isn't properly written. What is proper is to say that considering the linear system of $n$ number of congruences $m\equiv -k\pmod{p_k^2}$ where $k$ is an integer with $1\le k\le n$ and $p_k$ are distinct primes (or even pairwise coprime numbers $\gt 1$), the system, by CRT, has a unique solution modulo $\prod_1^n p_k^2$ and thus we can construct $n$ consecutive integers $m+k$ with $1\le k\le n$ such that none of them are square-free ($m+k$ is divisible by $p_k^2$)

Comment: Is this a translation from some other language?  The more usual terminology I've seen is "square-free" instead of "free of squares".

Comment: A little, yes. Because I'm just studying language from books and stuff. And I still look like a translator. @DanielSchepler

Comment: Thank you very much for completing the idea and helping me with the exercise. I appreciate :). @PrasunBiswas

Comment: Every fourth number is divisible by $4$.

Comment: @KeithBackman: But you cannot have consecutive numbers with every fourth number. ;) Of course, that makes verification simpler but construction difficult because you then cannot invoke CRT to get a unique residue modulo the product of the divisors as the starting point of those $n$ consecutive integers.

Comment: The proof is valid, if you do not want to get a "small" or even the optimal solution. This does not seem to be a requirement, so it is absolutely fine.